# Snowpipe REST API throwing HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Submitting on behalf of a Snowflake User...)

---

I am using Snowpipe REST endpoints to load files from external stage created for GCS (Google Cloud Storage). When I try to invoke Snowpipe to load files. I am getting the below error response when invoked through postman.

```
<title>Error 500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /v1/data/pipes/<pipe>/insertFiles. Reason:

<pre> Internal Server Error</pre>
```

I was also using java client to do the same and it is also failing with same reason

```
[main] WARN net.snowflake.ingest.connection.ServiceResponseHandler - Exceptional Status Code found in unmarshallInsert Response - 500
[main] ERROR net.snowflake.ingest.connection.ServiceResponseHandler - Status code 500 found in response from service

HTTP Status: 500
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head>
```

I am creating the tables/schema myself and invoking the REST API. Finding that the same thing works for other user who is doing the same thing as me. It is totally strange. Could you please help?

---

Any recommendations?  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend based on some research the following:

1. Check out the Copy History report of the query for more information [found here on how](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-ts.html#step-2-view-the-copy-history-for-the-table) please share this if you can.
2. Make sure that the users/role has permissions for [what you were invoking on](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-ts.html#step-1-checking-authentication-issues).
3. What is the status of the pipe?

The Snowpipe troubleshooting reference will help, but it is very likely the user role does not have permission to run the query.